# Como forçar exibição de teclado numérico no smartphone ao clicar em um input?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho um campo no meu formulário com `type="text"` e possui mascará para o  CEP. Quando acesso pelo celular e clico no campo preciso acionar o teclado número. Alguém sabe me dizer se tem alguma possibilidade de abrir o teclado numérico automático?

Comment: Tente <input type="number" pattern="\d*">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Infelizmente o `inputmode` só possui suporte no Chrome ([Can I
>   Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-inputmode)).

Pode usar `type="tel"`.
Esse type irá abrir o teclado numérico da discagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 8):

No html5 você pode utilizar o inputmode:

```
<input inputmode="numeric">
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui resolver com sua resposta e a do @dvd. Marquei a dele como resolvida por causa da questão de compatibilidade do inputmode.

Comment: show. muito bom

Answer (score 1):

Vale lembrar que CEP é um texto que é composto com caracteres numéricos, então não faz sentido utilizar o campo `number`. Como já comentado, no HTML 5 existe o atributo `inputmode` que pode ser utilizado para auxiliar dispositivos que exibem teclados virtuais em suas formas que facilitam o preenchimento do campo.

Os possíveis valores deste atributo são:

- `none`: nenhum teclado será exibido;
- `text`: teclado textual conforme localização do usuário;
- `decimal`: teclado numérico fracional;
- `numeric`: teclado numérico;
- `tel`: teclado telefônico - numérico incluindo as teclas <kbd>*</kbd> e <kbd>#</kbd> (é preferível utilizar o `<input type="tel">`);
- `search`: teclado virtual otimizado para buscas;
- `email`: teclado textual para e-mails (é preferível utilizar `<input type="email">`);
- `url`: teclado textual para URLs (é preferível utilizar `<input type="url">`);

Você pode ler mais na especificação [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#attr-inputmode) e ver o suporte atual no [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-inputmode).

Answer (score -2):

No HTML5 foram adicionados novos tipos de type para o campo input

```
<input type="number">
```

Para adicionar a mascara do tipo CEP editando o data-mask como abaixo

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Ex.: 00000-000" data-mask="00000-00" type="text">
```

Comment: Se eu colocar tipo number não vai aceitar a mascara 99999-999